# In UC Browser I am unable to download after display lock

Tags: lumia-640-xl, uc-browser

i am using Latest Microsoft Lumia 640 XL for last 2 months . I am unable to download in UC after Display Lock.  Why?

Comment: Do you mean "unable to download whilst screen is locked", or "unable to download after the screen is unlocked"

Answer (score 4):

You can choose option **"Background Download**" when options comes when a list appears and you press *download* in UC Browser. In case of choosing **"Regular Download"** this problem occurs.
Hope you got your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You may try UC Browser PC version.

its downloading function is more stable than phone.

also it can download Facebook videos.

here's the link to the official website: http://pc.ucweb.com/?from=ghx0005